# Firebase .orderBy function doesn't work on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with `orderBy` function. I try to make a social media app using Flutter and Firebase. User status shows on feed page.

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('following')
        .doc(widget.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('Following')
        .get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      List<String> authorId = snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('status')
            .where('authorId',
            whereIn: authorId)
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot2) {
          if (!snapshot2.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot2.data!.docs.length == 0) {
            return Text("Gösterilecek Bir Şey Yok");
          }
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot2.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Status status = Status.fromDoc(document);
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

              return FutureBuilder(
                future: usersRef.doc(data['authorId']).get(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot3) {
                  if (!snapshot3.hasData) {
                    return const SizedBox.shrink();
                  } else {
                    UserModel userModel = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot3.data);
                    
                    return StatusContainer(
                        status: status,
                        author: userModel,
                        currentUser: widget.currentUser);
                  }
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

When I use the `orderBy` function, no data is displayed on the screen. The `CircularProgressIndicator` widget works.

When I delete the function, it comes out in an unordered way. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: You're probably missing an index. Can you check your logs? There should be a link there that points you toward the index page and automatically makes an index for you. You can print `snapshot.error` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to create an index, but don't worry, you will see on your logs a url that will create the index for you.

Comment: Ah, I didnt see it. I added breakpoint and then I saw :) thx for ur help